# Chrome jQuery form plugin cross-domain security bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I'm trying to use [jQuery Form Plugi](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/)n to handle file uploads in an ajax form.

Everything works as long as I don't have an input[type=file] in the form.

When I add a file input type to the form, it will upload the file and work as it is supposed to in FireFox, but I get this error in Chrome:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access
>   frame with URL
>   http://swbdev.net:8888/inc/ajax/edit_page/
>   from frame with URL
>   http://swbdev.net:8888/site-pages-edit/19d8bb79c95e164f736f324d1b09a33e/1/#add_elements.
>   Domains, protocols and ports must
>   match.

It clearly states the Domain, protocols and ports must match. Am I missing something, in that same error it shows the two URLs and the domain, protocol and port all match?

Here is the JavaScript calling the plugin:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
        success:    function(data) { 
            alert(data); 
        },
        dataType: 'html',
        url: '/inc/ajax/edit_page/'
    }; 
    $('#add_elements_form').ajaxForm(options); 
 });
</script>
```

**MORE INFO:**

It's now failing in FireFox as well, not sure why it worked earlier, but here is the error in FireFox:

> Permission denied for
>   http://swbdev.net:8888 to get
>   property Location.href

It points to this area of code in the plugin:

```
            function cb() {
            if (xhr.aborted) {
                return;
            }
            var doc = io.contentWindow ? io.contentWindow.document : io.contentDocument ? io.contentDocument : io.document;
            if (!doc || doc.location.href == s.iframeSrc) {
                // response not received yet
                if (!timedOut) return;
            }
            io.detachEvent ? io.detachEvent('onload', cb) : io.removeEventListener('load', cb, false);
            var ok = true;
```

Specifically, this line:

```
 if (!doc || doc.location.href == s.iframeSrc
```

Comment: Adding: document.domain to the .php file that the AJAX is being posted to solved this problem, but makes it much harder to interpret and parse the return data...

Comment: Yes. I added JavaScript (document.domain) to the PHP file being called in the AJAX query.

Comment: can you write exactly what you wrote to the php file? Was it the destination file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely weird.  I would try setting the whole thing to "POST" since the input[type=file] will require that.  Of course it should work even mixed, but give this a try.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
        success:    function(data) { 
            alert(data); 
        },
        dataType: 'html',
        type: 'POST',   // <-- This was added
        url: '/inc/ajax/edit_page/'
    }; 
    $('#add_elements_form').ajaxForm(options); 
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this had no bearing... Thank you though.

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into the same issue with jquery file upload. Error was same as David B had

"Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://swbdev.net:8888/inc/ajax/edit_page/ from frame with URL http://swbdev.net:8888/site-pages-edit/19d8bb79c95e164f736f324d1b09a33e/1/#add_elements. Domains, protocols and ports must match."

In my case both calling page url and file-upload url were pointed to xxx.mydomain.com, but when the calling page was loaded, one javascript was setting document.domain to mydomain.com and was causing the error. Checking for document.domain after the calling page was loaded, revealed the issue and fixed by removing the document.domain line in javascript for xxx.mydomain.com